# I am submiting form in jquery whose response open in iframe which is PDF now i want to open that iframe as dialog please help me below is my code

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

This is my js part

function openFiles(fileSlNo) {

```
document.forms[0].method = "POST";
document.forms[0].target = "test";
document.forms[0].action = "folderNavigation.do?pageMode=DOWNLOAD_FILE&fileSlno="
        + fileSlNo;
document.forms[0].submit();
```

}

```
<div id="content">
          <iframe id="displayframe" name="test"></iframe> 
    </div>
```

please tell me how to do this? Thanks in advance

Comment: You said you are using jQuery? I only see javascript here. Please post your code.

Comment: sorry Apul Gupta i want to use jquery instead of java script to display my files in iframe as a dialog so please help me how to do that thanks

Comment: As per the description & comment, You are trying to post some parameters to server & in response of that you need IFRAME with a src.
Please confirm.

Comment: for action i am using  struts inline method for sending the stream to display pdf now i am sending that response to the iframe as i mentioned in the above code snipplet

Comment: That is fine. The overall thing I understood is, you need an ajax to post some parameters to your struts & you will send a response which needs to be shown in an IFRAME inside a popup

Comment: ya for that action i need to display my pdf file as a popup iframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the description & comment, You are trying to post some parameters to server & in response, you need to provide path to PDF.

Here is the code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="showDialog" title="Your Dialog Title Here" style="display: none;">

</div>
<form name="frmDemo" action="" method="post">
<input type="text" id="fileSlNo" name="fileSlNo" />
<input type="submit" value="Show Dialog" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

    $('form').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var fileSlNo = $('#`').val();
        var data     = { pageMode: 'DOWNLOAD_FILE', fileSlno: fileSlNo };
        $.ajax({
            type: POST, 
            url:, 'folderNavigation.do',
            data: data,
            success: function(responseData){
                // supposing responseData is the url of PDF
                $('#showDialog').dialog('destroy'); 
                $('#showDialog').html('<iframe src="'+responseData+'"></iframe>').dialog({
                    height:400,
                    modal: true
                });
            }       
        });

    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: my responseData itself is containing the outputstream not the url link